# Why does this synchronization primitive work effectively?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, language-agnostic

Probably many of us found or came up with the following synchronization primitive:

Acquiring lock (the code is in Pascal):

```
while Cardinal(InterlockedExchange(fAccess, 1)) <> 0 do 
  Sleep(0);
```

and releasing it:

```
InterlockedExchange(fAccess, 0);
```

When I found that it's not compatible with nested calls, I decided to make it better and implemented the new Aqcuire variant as the following code (let's call the fragments above Acquire/Release)

```
Acquired:=false;
repeat
  Acquire;
    if (fData.Thread = 0) or (fData.Thread = GetCurrentThreadId) then
    begin
      fData.Thread:=GetCurrentThreadId;
      Inc(fData.Level);
      Acquired:=true;
    end
    else
      Inc(fData.Failures);

    SleepAfter:=(not Acquired);
  Release;

  if SleepAfter then
    Sleep(0);
until Acquired;
```

and new Release

```
  Acquire;
    Dec(fData.Level);
    if fData.Level=0 then
      fData.Thread := 0
  Release;
```

This works, but what puzzles me is the low number of Failures (at least on a single-core system). For three  test threads increasing a value 10,000,000 times each, the number of times this code could not acquire the lock was about 72. I'm glad, but on the other side I can not understand the mechanics behind. So any waking thread finds that all other threads are sleeping most of the time. Why? And will the number of collisions grow significantly if the threads live on different cores?

Comment: You are testing this on a single-core system?  There's no point, surely?